# 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined' nodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo esta consulta

getAnalisisDetallado: function(req, res, next) {

```
var config = require('.././database/config');

sql.connect(config).then(function() {
    var articulos = null;
    var request = new sql.Request();
    request.query("SELECT TOP 10  SI_Id_Inventario, SI_Articulo, SI_UM, SI_Ubicacion FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD").then(function(err, rows, recordset) {
        articulos = rows || [];
        console.log('Recordset: ' + recordset);
        console.log('Affected: ' + request.rowsAffected);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Request error: ' + err);
    });
}).catch(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('SQL Connection Error: ' + err);
    }

});
sql.close();
// send records as a response 
res.render('menu/analisisDetallado', { ListArticulos: articulos });
```

}

y necesito agregar lo que me trae en una tabla

```
  div(class="container aDetallado")
    div(class="row center span10")
      table(id="test-table" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed")
        thead
          tr
            th='ID'
            th='Articulo'
            th='Um'
            th='#Ubic'        
          tbody
            each Articulos in ListArticulos
              tr
                td= Articulos.SI_Id_Inventario
                td= Articulos.SI_Articulo
                td= Articulos.SI_UM
                td= Articulos.SI_Ubicacion
```

y me sale el siguiente error

> TypeError: D:\Proyecto Inventario Fisico
>   Soc\InventarioF\views\menu\analisisDetallado.jade:59
>       57|             th='Ubic'
>       58|           tbody
>
> > 59|             each Articulos in ListArticulos
> >         60|               tr
> >         61|                 td= Articulos.SI_Id_Inventario
> >         62|                 td= Articulos.SI_Articulo
>
> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: ¿Ves error en la consola? En el condicional, de error, deberías informar en lugar de renderizar un lista que será `undefined` o, en su defecto, asignar un array vacío a la lista.

Comment: Que dependencia importas para sql?

Comment: ¿Qué librería usas para conectarte a la base de datos?

Comment: npm install mssql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.render` está siendo llamado antes de que el promise de `sql.connect` sea resuelto y además la variable `articulos` no está declarada en el mismo scope que la llamada a `res.render`.

Recuerda que todo el código dentro del callback de `.then` es asíncrono.

La solución propuesta es mover las lineas:

```
sql.close();
res.render('menu/analisisDetallado', { ListArticulos: articulos });
```

dentro de la llamada a `.then` de `request.query`

```
{
    getAnalisisDetallado: function(req, res, next) {

        var config = require('.././database/config');

        sql.connect(config)
            .then(function () {
                var articulos = null;
                var request = new sql.Request();
                request.query("SELECT TOP 10  SI_Id_Inventario, SI_Articulo, SI_UM, SI_Ubicacion FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD")
                    .then(function (result) {
                        articulos = result.recordset || [];
                        console.log('Recordset: ' + result.recordset);
                        console.log('Affected: ' + request.rowsAffected);
                        sql.close();
                        res.render('menu/analisisDetallado', { ListArticulos: articulos });
                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        console.log('Request error: ' + err);
                    });
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('SQL Connection Error: ' + err);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya la modifique pero la consola me dice lo siguiente 
`Recordset: undefined`
`Affected: 0`

Comment: acabo de editar la respuesta, basándome en este [ejemplo](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql/blob/1893969195045a250f0fdeeb2de7f30dcf6689ad/README.md#promises) he modificado el callback del promise de `request.query `, aún no lo tengo claro si recordset es un array

Comment: Ahora mi dice lo siguiente `Recordset: [object Object]`

Comment: Lo solucione con está forma  `articulos = recordset['recordset'];`

Comment: genial, lo actualicé en la respuesta cambiando `recordset['recordset']` por `result.recordset` basándome en el [ejemplo](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#query-command-callback) de la versión 4.x, fue incorrecto que haya asumido la forma de la versión 3.x, gracias

Answer (score 1):

me parece que el problema está aquí:

```
// quito el request.query porque el formato queda poco legible
.then(function(err, rows, recordset) {
                if (err) console.log(err)
                articulos = rows;
                ....
```

El problema es que, si te falla el `promise` ese que estás llamando, de todas formas llamas a

```
res.render('menu/analisisDetallado', { ListArticulos: articulos });
```

Tienes que buscar una forma de garantizar (en caso de que tengas que llamarlo siempre) que articulos tenga un array.

```
 articulos = rows || [];
```

El codigo de arriba te debe funcionar. Si rows viene `undefined` o `null` entonces le asignas un arreglo vacio.

**EDITADO**

El error de con los `Promise` te sale porque no manejas los resultados fallidos. Te pongo un ejemplo

```
var articulo = []
then(function () {
     console.log("Aqui fue bien");
     articulo = rows
}).catch(function () {
     console.log("Aqui fue mal");
});

res.render('menu/analisisDetallado', { ListArticulos: articulos });
```

Comment: Es correcto, pero es mucho mejor que se **informe** del posible error al usuario, ya que, de otro modo, este pensará que todo ha salido bien.

Comment: Entonces la consulta es mala por que no me trae nada.?

Comment: @Eduard la consulta te debe estar retornando un error. ¿Que te sale en pantalla con `console.log`?

Comment: Ya la modifique para que me salga el error y me dice lo siguiente `Unhandled promise rejection`

Comment: @Eduard mira el *addendum*.

Comment: Ya la modifique pero ahora me dice que articulos no esta definida.

Comment: @Eduard Hice un nuevo cambio

Answer (score 0):

Según la librería [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql), en su versión **4.x** puedes usar funciones asíncronas, para esto necesitas [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) o superior:

**getAnalisisDetallado (datos)**

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const config = require('../../database/config');

const getAnalisisDetallado = async function () {
  try {
    await sql.connect();
    const request = new sql.Request();
    const articulos = request.query`SELECT TOP 10  SI_Id_Inventario, SI_Articulo, SI_UM, SI_Ubicacion FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD`;
    return articulos;
  } catch(e) {
    throw new Error(e.message);
  }
}
```

**getAnalisisDetallado (handler)**

```
getAnalasisDetallado = (req, res) => {
  getAnalisisDetallado()
    .then(articulos => {
      res.render('menu/analisisDetallado', { ListaArticulos: articulos });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.render('menu/analisisDetallado', { ListaArticulos: [], error: err });
    });
}
```

En la versión **3.x**, puedes usar cualquier versión vieja ([nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) 4.x+), ya que no hay soporte para funciones asíncronas:

```
const getAnalisisDetallado = async function () {
  return (
    sql
      .connect()
      .then((resolve, reject) => {
        const request = new sql.Request();
        request
          .query('SELECT TOP 10  SI_Id_Inventario, SI_Articulo, SI_UM, SI_Ubicacion FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD')
          .then((err, rows, recorset) => {
            if (err) { reject(err.message); }
            resolve(rows);
          });
      })
  );
}
```